# Laravel Undefined variable in where clause

Tags: php, laravel, controller

I'm trying to get the id query parameter from the url. After that, I want to compare the ID in url with artwork ID in database is it the same, then proceed to other action.

However, the $artworks()->id in the where clause is count as undefined variable. The problem is Undefined Variable: artworks. May I know which part I have do wrong?

```
public function show($id)
{
    if(filled($id)){
        $artworks   = Artwork::all()->where($id,'=',$artworks()->id);
        $categories = Category::all();
        $artist = User::all();
        return view('pages.artwork-detail', compact('categories', 'artworks','artist'));
    }else{
        echo("The id does not exist.");
    }

}
```

Comment: `$artworks` is not defined. Where did you expect that to come from?

Comment: If you're trying to find the artwork that matches the ID, then you just need [`Artwork::find($id)`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#retrieving-single-models)

Comment: @aynber because I'm also want to get all the data from the Artwork table and display it in view. Can it still retrieve all the data by using Artwork::find($id)?

Comment: `find` will get all the data for 1  artwork. If you want all of the artwork records, then you really don't need the id at all.

Comment: The `show($id)` route is typically for displaying a *single* record from the database. The `index()` route is typically where you show all the records from a database table. Figure out your requirements and use the correct routing conventions. Beyond that, you have a lot of issues with your code; `$artworks = $artworks()->id;` is nonsensical; `$artworks` is not defined yet, nor is it a method. `::all()->where()` is also really bad, as it loads every record from the DB just to then find one. Use `::find($id)` or `::where('id', $id)->first()`, etc. Please review the docs and fix your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if my answer will work, but I can definetely fix some issues in your code.

```
public function show($id)
{
    if(!filled($id)) return echo("The id does not exist.");
    
    // I don't know $id belongs to what. If it's artworks' id:
    $artworks   = Artwork::findOrFail($id);
    // Otherwise, let's say it's user_id on the artworks table:
    $artworks   = Artwork::where('user_id', $id)->get();
    // But if it's, use the following line instead of the other one.
    
    
    $categories = Category::all();
    
    $artist = User::all();
    
    return view(
        'pages.artwork-detail',
         compact('categories', 'artworks', 'artist')
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do it this way:

```
public function show($id)
{
    if(filled($id)){
        $artworks   = Artwork::find($id);
        $categories = Category::all();
        $artist = User::all();
        return view('pages.artwork-detail', compact('categories', 
               'artworks','artist'));
     }else{
       echo("The id does not exist.");
    }

}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try these where condition

```
$artworks   = Artwork::where('id','=', $id)->get();

$artworks   = Artwork::where('id', $id)->get();

$artworks   = Artwork::find($id);
```

if you need just one record try these where condition

```
$artworks   = Artwork::where('id','=', $id)->first();

$artworks   = Artwork::where('id', $id)->first();

$artworks   = Artwork::find($id);
```